# Protractor - dragging from desktop

Tags: protractor

Does anyone have an idea how in a protractor test I might choose a file from the desktop and then drop it on an element in my page?

I presume it's a matter of using data to represent the file (path etc) in some format and then dropping that on the destination control, but that's a guess...

The scenario I am looking at is a file upload where there isn't a "File" input (at least not yet), but uses Javascript instead to respond when the user drops a file on a specific element.

Comment: Give this package a try https://www.npmjs.com/package/robotjs

Comment: Thanks for the tip... I'll see if I can get time to do it later.